# What is the name of this root finding method?

Tags: python, algorithm

I recently stumbled across the algorithm below for finding roots. I first thought it was some sort of bracketing. But it's somewhat simpler, by just going through a certain interval and directly check whether there is (approx) a root. Is there a name for that method? You could of course extend, in order to find every root in the given interval. Now it directly returns you the `x` value, assuming there is only one root in the given interval.

```
def function(f, R, steps=1001, tol=1e-10):    
    x_low, x_high = R    
    points = np.linspace(x_low, x_high, steps)    
    for point in points:        
        if abs(f(point)) < tol:
            return point
```

Comment: I've heard this method called "brute force." e.g. [scipy.optimize.brute](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html)

Comment: This method might not find the root at all. If the range is too large or `steps` is too small, none of the points will be close to 0.

Comment: That's what I also thought, just trying to brute force it. Not very sophisticated but does the job. @Barmar: That's a problem of many numerical techniques.